# How to create Sessions in Java

Tags: java, session

I have a stand-alone/ desktop application written in Java. I'd like to add a functionality that allows users to be able to log in as well as log out. Is there a way to go about this in Java. I'm sure there is, but what I get so far relates to web applications and servelets.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Well, use a dialog box asking the user credentials, check them, and once checked, store the user information in a variable somewhere. What's the difficulty exactly?

Comment: What do you mean by session? Do you want to let user be logged in even after restarting application (like in http sessions)? What is your issue here?

Comment: Sessions in a desktop application are a little nonsensical - the idea of a session is to identify you and your current state to a remote server that may be dealing with many users simultaneously. What role do they have in a desktop application? Authentication is another question.

Comment: Thanks [@JB Nizet](http://stackoverflow.com/users/571407/jb-nizet). I got so caught up in web applications I thought I had to follow the same course in desktop apps.

Comment: if you want to store the details/activities related to a particular user till the time he logs out, you can create your independent Map/Table. basically session also consists of serialized objects mapped to session id.